# how to copy file from local git to server filesystem?

Tags: python, django, fabric

I am looking for a way to automate a deployment script.
I choose to use fabric.

I can't figure out if there is a way to copy the local changed files to the server.
I have seen many examples, but they all using github or an origin git installed in the server.

I would like to do something like :

```
get changed files from local and add them in server
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["git","pull","fromlocalmachine"])
```

Comment: this run on local machine, we have already have local for that.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Synthetica's answer, is is a simple deployment script that, grabbed from [sametmax.com](http://sametmax.com/travailler-moins-pour-gagner-plus-en-15-minutes-avec-python-fabric/):

```
from fabric.api import local, run, cd, env, prefix

REMOTE_WORKING_DIR = '/path/to/project'

env.hosts = ['siteweb.com']
env.user = 'username'

def push(branch='master', remote='origin', runlocal=True):
    if runlocal:
        # run command locally
        local("git push %s %s" % (remote, branch))
    else:
        # run command on remote hosts
        run("git push %s %s" % (remote, branch))

def pull(branch='master', remote='origin', runlocal=True):
    if runlocal:
        local("git pull %s %s" % (remote, branch))
    else:
        run("git pull %s %s" % (remote, branch))

def sync(branch='master', remote='origin', runlocal=True):
    pull(branch, remote, runlocal)
    push(branch, remote, runlocal)

def deploy(branch='master', remote='origin'):
    with cd(REMOTE_WORKING_DIR):
        with prefix('workon virtualenv'): # replace by your virtual env name
            pull(branch, remote, False)
            run("./manage.py collectstatic --noinput")
```

Now, you can run `fab sync` to sync your git repository with your git server, and `fab deploy` to deploy it.
(or `fab sync deploy` to do both).

Comment: that is ok, since you have git on your web server and you have a git bare repository somewhere accessible from your web server and your local machine. I dont have git on my server. Is it possible to push the changed files directly to the remote server?

Comment: I use it with Git installed on the deployment server. I you want to deploy without using Git, I think you'll need to transfer files via FTP, but I don't know any ready-to-use script for that. IMHO, it's easier to install git on deployment server.